# Как фильтровать данные на клиенте?

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc

Есть следующее представление:

```js
angular.module('app', []).controller('ctrl', function($scope) {
  var types = [{
    name: 'Аварийная',
    selected: false
  }, {
    name: 'Плановая',
    selected: false
  }];
  var requests = [{
    id: 1,
    type: 'Аварийная'
  }, {
    id: 2,
    type: 'Плановая'
  }, {
    id: 3,
    type: 'Аварийная'
  }, {
    id: 4,
    type: 'Плановая'
  }];
  $scope.types = types;
  $scope.requests = requests;
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0/angular.js"></script>
<div class="container" ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
      Параметры отчета
    </div>
    <div class="panel-body">
      <div class="form-group" ng-repeat="type in types">
        <div class="checkbox">
          <label>
            <input type="checkbox" ng-model="type.selected" />{{type.name}}</label>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <table class="table table-bordered">
      <tr>
        <td>№</td>
        <td>Тип заявки</td>
      </tr>
      <tr ng-repeat="request in requests">
        <td>{{request.id}}</td>
        <td>{{request.type}}</td>
      </tr>
    </table>

  </div>
</div>
```

Подскажите как необходимо *отфильтровать* данные, т.е. пользователь отмечает необходимые *Типы* а в таблице отображаются только соответствующие данные?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Так как флаги уже есть, по ним и стоит фильтровать, для этого в фильтре нужно указывать не `name`, а `selected`.

```js
angular.module('app', []).controller('ctrl', function($scope) {
  var types = [{
    name: 'type 1',
    selected: false
  }, {
    name: 'type 2',
    selected: false
  }, {
    name: 'type 3',
    selected: false
  }, ];
  $scope.types = types;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0/angular.js"></script>
<div class="container" ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
      Параметры отчета
    </div>
    <div class="panel-body">
      <div class="form-group" ng-repeat="type in types">
        <div class="checkbox">
          <label>
            <input type="checkbox" ng-model="type.selected" />{{type.name}}</label>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <table>
      <tr>Тип</tr>
      <tr ng-repeat="type in types | filter:{selected:true}">
        <td>{{type.name}}</td>
      </tr>
    </table>

  </div>
</div>
```

**Обновление**
Параметром функции `filter`, может быть не только объект с полями, по которым надо фильтровать, но и функция, которая по данному элементу должна вернуть подходит он к фильтру или нет.

Например

```js
angular.module('app', []).controller('ctrl', function($scope) {
  var types = [{
    name: 'Аварийная',
    selected: false
  }, {
    name: 'Плановая',
    selected: false
  }];
  var requests = [{
    id: 1,
    type: 'Аварийная'
  }, {
    id: 2,
    type: 'Плановая'
  }, {
    id: 3,
    type: 'Аварийная'
  }, {
    id: 4,
    type: 'Плановая'
  }];
  $scope.types = types;
  $scope.requests = requests;

  // если тип выбран
  $scope.checker = function(el) {
    return types.some(function(t) {
      return t.selected && t.name == el.type
    });
  }
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0/angular.js"></script>
<div class="container" ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
      Параметры отчета
    </div>
    <div class="panel-body">
      <div class="form-group" ng-repeat="type in types">
        <div class="checkbox">
          <label>
            <input type="checkbox" ng-model="type.selected" />{{type.name}}</label>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <table class="table table-bordered">
      <tr>
        <td>№</td>
        <td>Тип заявки</td>
      </tr>
      <tr ng-repeat="request in requests | filter:checker">
        <td>{{request.id}}</td>
        <td>{{request.type}}</td>
      </tr>
    </table>

  </div>
</div>
```